# Is there a way of chaining multiple models and query them in a single response?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

Hi i'm new to Django and need a little help. I'm building an API using Django and Graphene for a news site. I created multiple post models for each news cast so that each news cast can just view their corresponding model in the Django Admin panel. The problem i'm facing is that i need to chain or combine all the models for a single query so i can display all of the posts created from all of the models.

In this example i imported both of the post model in the schema file. Is this the right approach if yes is there a way of chaining them into a single query?

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import News, Sport

class NewsType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = News

class SportType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Sport

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    news = graphene.List(NewsType)
    sports = graphene.List(SportType)

    def resolve_news(self, info):
        return News.objects.all()

    def resolve_sports(self, info):
        return Sports.objects.all()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If both models have same fields AND graphene allow to use list instead queryset in resolvers, then you can simply use [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
chained_results = list(chain(News.objects.all(), Sports.objects.all()))
```

Comment: Yes both models have the same fields, but i don't understand how to check if my resolver is allowed to use list instead queryset. If you have the time i would really much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is where i'm at now.
Both Post and Post2 models have the same fields.

schema.py

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import Post, Post2
from itertools import chain
from graphene import relay

class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

class Post2Type(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Post2

class AssetUnion(graphene.types.Union):
    class Meta:
        types = [Post, Post2]

class ParentNode(graphene.ObjectType):
    assets = graphene.Field(AssetUnion)
    def resolve_assets(self, info):
        return list(chain(Post.objects.all(), Post2.objects.all()))

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    post = graphene.List(PostType)
    post2 = graphene.List(Post2Type)

    def resolve_post(self, info):
        return Post.objects.all()

    def resolve_post2(self, info):
        return Post2.objects.all()
```

I get this response

```
{
  "data": {
    "post": [
      {
        "title": "post 1"
      }
    ],
    "post2": [
      {
        "title": "post test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What i want to get is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allPost": [
      {
        "title": "post 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "post test"
      }
  }
}
```